Reverse Right to left text with examples
I want to get this
The text comes as a sample like this
sample
This:
hello all my name nora
like this:
nora name my all hello
Of course, the important point is that this is not just for one text, I need several texts to appear in this way at the same time, thanks.
if It is possible with Regex in notepad++ or tool, I will be grateful Thank 

If you have awk: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46281

In Notepad++ if you don't mind to click multiple times on "replace all" you could swap two words on a go and place a marker such as # for replaced words. Search for (?<!\S)(\w+)(.*)(?<!\S)(\w+) and replace all with #$3$2#$1 until no more matches are found, finally replace the # with empty.

I haven't heard of such tool. However, I created this simple program. It can be run across different OS. Just plug in the name of the files you want to reverse the lines from and the whole file (each line their own) will be reversed.
e.g
file.txt
consequat quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
eu fugiat nulla pariatur Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident

e.g (after the program is run)
file.txt
aliquip ut nisi laboris ullamco exercitation nostrud quis consequat
laborum est id anim mollit deserunt officia qui culpa in sunt
proident non cupidatat occaecat sint Excepteur pariatur nulla fugiat eu

program source code and usage:
python
A programmers approach to this:
Save this piece of program in a .py file (script.py, for instance)
Then on your terminal:
import argparse
import os

def reverse_sentences_in_file(input_file):
    # Read the file
    with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    # Process each line
    reversed_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        # Strip newline characters and split the line into words
        words = line.strip().split()
        # Reverse the order of words
        reversed_words = words[::-1]
        # Join the reversed words back into a sentence
        reversed_line = ' '.join(reversed_words)
        # Append the reversed sentence to the list
        reversed_lines.append(reversed_line)

    # Write the reversed sentences back to the same file
    with open(input_file, 'w') as file:
        for reversed_line in reversed_lines:
            file.write(reversed_line + '\n')

def main():
    # Setup argument parser
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Reverse sentences in multiple files.")
    parser.add_argument('files', metavar='F', type=str, nargs='+', help='a list of files to process')

    # Parse arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Reverse sentences in each file
    for input_file in args.files:
        if os.path.isfile(input_file):
            reverse_sentences_in_file(input_file)
            print(f"Reversed sentences have been written to {input_file}.")
        else:
            print(f"File {input_file} does not exist.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

app usage:
python script.py name_of_the_file_you_want_to_reverse.txt

Thank I think this is the answer to my problem. Does this tool also work for Arabic or Farsi?

Sure thing, @omidleon. Also, you could use an unlimited amount of files as arguments on your terminal, so python script.py file_0.txt file_1.txt file_2.txt ... file_n.txt

Dear @victorkolis Your tool made my work ok, you are amazing, thank you for helping me

I will definitely start learning Python

C#
string str = "hello all my name nora";
string[] strarr = str.Split(' ');
string result = "";

for (int i = strarr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    result += (result != "") ? " " + strarr[i] : strarr[i];
}

MessageBox.Show(result);


You could also consider using the Array.Reverse method. Once you have your array of strings you call the Reverse method and then Join the results back into a string.

Thanks dear friend ♥️♥️ For this code, I must install Visual Studio to compile, or I can use Visual Code ?

@omidleon Yes, you can use it to VS Code.

Dear friend, your tool also worked. Thank you
